# xcode MKMapView did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, mobile-development

I Had these errors while writing a map in xcode:

```
2021-01-09 19:02:48.228694+0100 BudapestBoards[31795:558225] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-01-09 19:02:48.433777+0100 BudapestBoards[31795:558225] This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data
2021-01-09 19:02:50.483788+0100 BudapestBoards[31795:558499] [MKCoreLocationProvider] CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x600002b2b5b0>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x600001b30360> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (B1F529FE-C1E7-4C0A-B918-A3C76E006F27) - Runtime: iOS 14.3 (18C61) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
```

i am using mapview.
my code is:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
 
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            if let location = locations.first {
                manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                render(location)
            }
        }
        func render(_ location: CLLocation) {
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Thanks for responding when adding a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription it says it is already present in the dictionary and if i want to replace it. if i press on replace it does not do anything except delete that line.

Answer (score 6):

The relevant information in this error is:

> This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a
> usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
> “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” key with a string value
> explaining to the user how the app uses this data

You need to provide a string in your `Info.plist` that explains why your app wants to access location information.

So locate the `Info.plist` file, add a new line with "`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`" as key and a text. The text is presented in the alert which asks the user, whether he allows access or not, so consider localising it.